# how to add enter key to calculate taxes?

Tags: javascript

id like to know how i can add onclick="calculer" to work with enter keyboard shortcut too. ive tried many code like this one

```
document.body.onkeydown = function(e) {
       if (e.keyCode == 13)
            validatePass();
    };
```

but nothing seems to work. sorry im a begginer at school only beeing able to post was complicated to me :P would be much appreciated

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <script>
        function calculer() {
            montant = Number(document.getElementById("montant").value);
            taxe = (montant * 14.975) / 100;
            total = (montant * 114.975) / 100;

            ment.getElementById("taxe").value = taxe + " $";
            ment.getElementById("total").value = total + " $";
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    Montant:
    <br />
    <input type="number" id="montant" />
    <br /><br />
    Taxe:
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="taxe" placeholder="$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$" readonly />
    <br /><br />
    Résultat:
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="total" placeholder="$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$" readonly />
    <br /><br />
    <button type="button" onclick="calculer()">Calculer</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add an event listener for a keyboard event that calls the function.

Comment: You have typo in your code. You wrote "ment.getElementById". It should be "document.getElementById"

Answer (score 0):

```js
const elementOne = document.getElementById('taxe');
const elementTwo = document.getElementById('taxe');
elementOne.addEventListener('keyup',(e) => {
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
    calculer()
    //use the same process for elementTwo
  } 
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should attach the event listener to the document.

Here's how you can do it:

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      calculer();
    }
  });
```

Comment: tyvm this solution did work